# Probability of splitting nucleus

Tags: atomic-physics, subatomic

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I was just wondering.

Say we have a 20 x 20 cm sheet of sulphur, and we have a knife made of iron. If I take the knife, and repeatedly cut the sulphur for an n number of times, what is the probability that I will once hit the sulphur at such a point where an atom had a nucleus, and the nucleus was cut? Is this physically possible? If not, and if atoms do physically exist, why isn't it possible?

Answer (score 0):

So no it is not possible to cut a nucleus or an atom in two, it is not even possible for two atoms to even touch because of electrostatic forces between the atoms. The electrons of both atoms will make two atoms strongly repel at some distance. At normal or usual distances, I should say, two atoms will barely have an effect on one another because the distance between those two atmos will be way larger than the distance between the positive nucleus and the negative electrons which are usually of the same number, so the electrostatic forces are basically the same.

Comment: So if the atoms do not touch, how do we feel whatever we "touch"?

Comment: Well there is still an interaction between atoms via electrostatic forces as I said.

Comment: What do you mean by "atoms" touch? The atoms can touch, or ever overlap each other. What you say is true for nuclei, not for "atoms"

Comment: distance between two hydrogen atoms is approximately 1.2 Angstroms, and their radius is 0.5 Angstroms. The atomic distance is such because atoms have effect on each other - wan der Waals interaction. Do you mean nuclei again?

Comment: You sure that the distance between two atoms is not the distance between the centers of the atoms. We don't usually measure distance  between the outer shells. And 1.2 angstroms of distance if perfectly acceptable in this case since that it is greater than twice the radius of the hydrogen atom.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to other answers, I would say that two atoms can definitely touch each other - this is why solid matter is "stiff" (minimum of van der Waals interaction is of the order of radius of an atomic cloud). The atoms can even overlap and they often do, say excited to a Rydberg state. In the latter case, the cloud of electrons encompasses other neutral atoms with no problem.

The problem is however, that both knife and the sulphur are made of atoms. So the knife is by no means "sharp" at the length scale of an atom. The cloud of electron gas of a first atom can encompass the second atom, but the attractive interaction between electrons of a first atom and a nucleus of a second atom will not cause the split of the nucleus - it is attractive and much weaker than strong interaction holding the nucleus together.

Two nuclei won't hit each other as they are both strongly positively charged and they repel each other.  It is possible to hit two nuclei together but this is done in the accelerator (then they indeed split forming new particles).